# Breadth-First Search Algorithm JAVA 8-puzzle

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, puzzle, breadth-first-search

Im trying to implement the   Breadth-First  algorithm for 8 puzzle game. I know that it is not a new case and theres a bunch of solutions on web, but I want to make it on my way of thinking.

This code already finds the node result, which is

```
123
456
780
```

But it takes 350,000 steps to do it!

Any thoughts would be appreciated!
=)

```
    //This method receives a Collection of `Nodo` objects, each one will be checked and compare with the finalGoal

     public void percorreNodos(Collection<Nodo> nodosBase)
            {
                //In this class a have an array that has all the IDs os nodes that already has been checked
                //The ID of a Node, is the representation: 123456780, 354126870 , etc..
                System.out.println("idsPercorrido.size() = " + idsPercorridos.size());
                //Check if the collection nodosBase contains the finalGoal
                Iterator<Nodo> iterator =  nodosBase.iterator();
                while( iterator.hasNext() )
                {
                    Nodo nodoBase = (Nodo) iterator.next();
                    //If this current node has already been checked, we dont have to check it again
                    idsPercorridos.add( nodoBase.getId() );
                            //Just print the node (sysout)
                    nodoBase.print();
                    contPassos++;
                    System.out.println( "\n" + contPassos + " STEPS(number of nodes checked)..." );
                    //Check if this node is the final goal
                    if( nodoBase.isObjetivoFinal() )
                    {
                                    //set the variable indicating that the result has been found
                        encontrouObjetivo = true;
                        System.out.println( "Resultado alcancado EM " + contPassos + " PASSOS..." );
                        nodoBase.print();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Now that we know that no one Node of nosoBase collection is the final goal, we are going to generate the next children to be checked, and call this function recursively 
                //Just confirm that we didnt find the goal 
                if(encontrouObjetivo == false)
                {
                            //Creates the next frontier
                    Collection<Nodo> novaFronteira = new HashSet<Nodo>();

                    for(Nodo nodoPai : nodosBase)
                    {
                                    //Generate each Node its childrens and add to a collection called "novaFronteira"
                        Collection<Nodo> filhos = nodoPai.gerarFilhos();
                        for(Nodo filho : filhos)
                        {
//idsPercorridos is a collection<String> which contains all the nodes ids that we checked, we dont want to check a node more than one time !
                            if( idsPercorridos.contains( filho.getId() ) == false )
                            {
                                novaFronteira.add( filho );

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    this.percorreNodos( novaFronteira );
                }

            }
```

Comment: You might want to change your variables names to be in English. It will probably help you get more responses.

Comment: In addition, this question is probably better suited for Code Review http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Just to point out -- the 8-puzzle has 9!/2 = 181,440 unique states reachable in a BFS due to parity. A breadth-first search usually starts at the initial state you've drawn above, and then searches outwards. If you are expecting to do less work, you should think about using a heuristic and an algorithm like IDA*.

Comment: Other people gave solutions to your problem, but as a matter of style, if you have `if(b == false)` anywhere, this is equivalent to the much simpler `if(!b)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make sure you don't add duplicate elements to `novaFronteira`.

There's nothing preventing this code:

```
for(Nodo nodoPai : nodosBase)
{
    Collection<Nodo> filhos = nodoPai.gerarFilhos();
    for(Nodo filho : filhos)
    {
        if( idsPercorridos.contains( filho.getId() ) == false )
        {
            novaFronteira.add( filho );
        }
    }
}
```

From adding many duplicate nodes to `novaFronteira`.

If you were to add to `idsPercorridos` inside the if-statement, that would prevent this from happening, and result in less steps, although, depending on exactly what your data and data structures looks like, the added running time of this call may actually make it take longer than it did originally.

---

If the problem is running time, you should make sure that `idsPercorridos` is a `TreeSet` or `HashSet`, as these allow for efficient `contains` calls, as opposed to `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`, which don't.

---

If this doesn't help, you could try using [the A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-star_algorithm) instead, which involves adding a heuristic function to each node, which is the distance to the target - this allows us to explore the nodes closer to the target first, often resulting in less steps to get there.

A good heuristic function might be the sum of [Manhattan distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) between each tile and its target location.

Note that this would involve quite a few changes to your current code.

Comment: Doesn't `idsPercorridos.add( nodoBase.getId() );` prevent duplicates?

Comment: @Khaelid It does, but it's called too late (or at least it looks like it is) - consider duplicate entries in `nodosBase` (which is possible, since the code sample shown in my answer doesn't prevent it) - these will all get processed even though they get added to `idsPercorridos` because there's no `idsPercorridos.contains` check inside the first while-loop (which would be another almost functionally-identical solution to the one I presented).

Comment: @Dukeling  It works, but know I realize that I can have duplicated nodes. What I can't is the same routes! Do you have any idea how can I make it possible? Thankss

Comment: @user2294899 Why do you want duplicate nodes? If you already reached some state, why do you want to reach that same state again later? But if you completely remove `idsPercorridos`, you'll no longer be checking for duplicate nodes (and you can't generate duplicate routes), but then you'd be back to plenty of steps (probably quite a bit more than you had originally).

Comment: @Dukeling I think for 8 puzzle soltution, is possible to reach same state again later but with different routes. That is what I need, because I code for not reach the same state again and there were 181,440 possiblities of nodes, but I didnt reach the goal state, even after check each state individually. =(

Comment: @user2294899 [Some initial board states are unsolvable](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall12/cos226/assignments/8puzzle.html). If your initial board state doesn't fall under those rules, and you still don't get a solution, you should consider posting an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: SOLVED . I could not achieve the goal state because it was a unsolvable state. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle) there are `9!/2 = 181440` possible solvable combinations to this puzzle. If you check each node for each of these combinations (which you don't, but it makes the calculation easier), it makes about `(9!/2) * 9 = 1,632,960` steps. Therefore, there I don't see an issue if it takes your algorithm `350,000` steps because a computer can do those steps *really* fast.